# How to calculate a set of sub rectangles which exactly cover a rectangle board with rectangular holes

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Say, I wanna scratch off some rectangular holes from a rectangle board. For example,

situation 1, holes intersect:

a borad x with hole 0,1,2 in it, rectangle 0 and 1 intersect.

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx222xx
x000xx222xx
x00011222xx
x00011xxxxx
xxx111xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

or simpler, situation 2, no holes intersect:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx2222xx
x00xx2222xx
x00xx2222xx
x00x111xxxx
xxxx111xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

The latter is more like 'invert a set of rectangles within a big rectangle'.

My Question is: How to calculate a set of sub rectangles which exactly cover the board x?

```
Input: a larger rect, and a set of hole rects  
Output: a set of sub rects cover exactly the larger rect with holes
```

the rect struct may like CCRect below, coordination type is float:

```
typedef struct {float x; float y;} CGPoint;
typedef struct {float width, float height} CGSize;
typedef struct {CGPoint origin; CGSize size;} CGRect;
```

Any great idea?

Comment: please give more information. What is the number of holes you expect. What do you mean by some small rectangles

Comment: I clarify the question a bit. The number of holes is not fixed, but not too many.

Comment: Are you asking for the best way to represent the rectangles, or for an algorithm to calculate how to fill the larger rectangle with smaller ones?

Comment: Would a set of rectangles be an acceptable output from the algorithm you want?

Comment: @tobias_k I'm asking an algorithm to calculate how to fill the larger rectangle with smaller ones

Comment: @Deestan Yes, the output is a set of rectangles which cover exactly the larger rectangle

Comment: Ah, I see.  Put the starting rectangle in set R, then apply each cut in turn to all rectangles in R. Applying a cut will transform a rectangle into 1, 2, 3, or 4 new rectangles. After applying a cut to a rectangle, remove it from R and insert the new rectangles into R. When all cuts have been processed, output R. --- I can probably knock out some pseudocode as an answer for this later, but right now this is all I have time for. :-)

Comment: @Deestan, good, your idea may work for the situation with no holes intersect

Comment: @smilingpoplar It should work equally well if holes intersect.

Comment: @Deestan, right, it works, just need a merge pass to reduce rectangle count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing constraint in your question. How do you want to optimize the result. Are you seeking for having fewer resulting rectangles as possible ?

Are the edges on a grid ?

I would do it like this :

- start with one big rectangle and a two methods, one for splitting rectangles, the other fo joining them
- split the main rectangle in two for each side of the hole rectangles. Extend their borders as much as possible and split the plane along this line. Once you've done that, you endup with lot of small rectangles. I guess you want to have as few rectangle as possible.
- Pass one - remove holes : For each little rectangle if the coordinate fill inside a hole rectangle you had in the begining, discard it.
- Pass two - join the remaining rectangles : for each rectangle, if it can form a rectangle with a neighbor, join them

This pass two is tricky, there are tons of optimisation to do there.
A simple optization will be to join alternatively verticaly then horizontaly. This way you will end up with bigger rectangles.

Edit:
You can speedup dramaticaly pass2 if you build a BSP tree during pass 1. Each time you split, it create a new node where 2 leaves are the child rectangles. It will make it much faster to find the neighbors in pass 2.

Comment: The less rectangles the better. The edges is not on a grid (coordination type float). Your 'two pass' idea is great.